# How do I enumerate a list comprehension with two 'for's?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, enumerate

I am trying to do

```
ls = [myfunc(a,b,i) for a in a_list for b in b_list]
```

but also pass in `i` into myfunc, which is an index starting at 0 and incrementing for each new element.

For example:

```
a_list = 'abc'
b_list = 'def'
```

should result in

```
ls = [myfunc('a','d',0),
      myfunc('a','e',1),
      myfunc('a','f',2),
      myfunc('b','d',3),
      myfunc('b','e',4),
      ...
      myfunc('c','f',8]
```

I know that I can use `enumerate()` for just the normal case, ie.

```
ls = [myfunc(a,i) for a,i in enumerate(a_list)]
```

But I can't figure out how to do it cleanly when there are two `for`s. I couldn't find this question posted previously either.

Comment: Do it in two steps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are creating a [Cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists) over two lists, so use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) instead of a double `for` loop. This gives you a single iterable you can easily add `enumerate()` to:

```
from itertools import product

ls = [myfunc(a, b, i) for i, (a, b) in enumerate(product(a_list, b_list))]
```

For cases where you can't use `product()`, you'd put the multiple loops in a generator expression, then add `enumerate()` to that. Say you needed to filter some values of `a_list`:

```
gen = (a, b for a in a_list if some_filter(a) for b in b_list)
ls = [myfunc(a, b, i) for i, (a, b) in enumerate(gen)]
```

Another option is to add a separate counter; [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) gives you a counter object that produces a new value with `next()`:

```
from itertools import count

counter = count()
ls = [myfunc(a, b, next(counter)) 
      for a in a_list if some_filter(a)
      for b in b_list]
```

After all, in essence `enumerate(iterable, start=0)` is the equivalent of `zip(itertools.count(start), iterable)`.

Comment: @tobias_k: that wasn't me. That was that guy over there with the paper bag over their head.

Comment: @PetterFriberg: *That's the one!* He keeps breaking into my house! They think I can't see them, but I can spot them when I walk past a mirror!

Answer (score 5):

You can use enumerate on the sequence of pairs.

```
ls = [myfunc(a,b,i) for (i,(a,b)) in
      enumerate((a,b) for a in a_list for b in b_list)]
```

Comment: I'll give you an upvote if you split that unreadable line into two readable ones (: Edit: That's not really what I meant, but it's readable enough I guess.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Sure.

Answer (score 2):

For a simple nested loop, use `itertools.product()` as @Martijn suggested.

If the expression is more complex you can use `itertools.count`:

```
i_gen = itertools.count()
ls = [myfunc(a, b, next(i_gen)) for a in a_list for b in b_list]
```